# SSL HttpWebRequest causes internal server error?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest

I am trying to write a login script, but for some reason I am getting an internal server error (500).

I tried this with PHP and cURL, there I got a response when I set the option `VERIFY_PEER = false`.

Here's the C# code:

```
    private void Login()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://whatever.com");
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = string.Format("user={0}&password={1}&submit=login", User, Password);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (x,y,z,a) => true;
        webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(responseStream.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anybody know why I am not getting a response?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Have you inspected the content of response and responseStream ?

Comment: It's crashing when getting the response from the webrequest. (internal server error 500).

Comment: Does not solve your problem, but when you set a method to ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, please note that this setting is "global" and not thread-safe....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake... It seems as if the server requieres a "valid" useragent. When setting firefox as a useragent, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the HTTP request/responses. You can set it up to intercept HTTPS traffic too. That way you can see exactly what your system is requesting.

From your comments your getting a 500 error, that normally means the url/request is malformed if it works from one script/app and not the other. This will let you see whats being request (and highlight any protocol error for you).